# How can a hive mind be prevented from learning new information?

Tags: physics, gods, brain

Entities from the spiritual realm must incarnate into the mortal world in order to communicate with humanity. This is done through the use of avatars, which are humanoid shells containing the soul of the entity. There are different types of avatars, each with their own characteristics. Purna avatars are full avatars and the strongest type, with the entity fully incarnating it's soul into one body. As the soul of an entity is massive, these forms can be large, measuring about 25ft. Ansha avatars are partial avatars, in which the entity only transfers a smaller version of itself into a body. This could be an aspect of itself that it represents, such as love or rage. As it contains a partial soul, they are generally human sized and can blend in much better with humanity. However, they lack the full powers of their counterparts. The concept of free will grows the further an avatar is removed from its original creator. As Purna avatars are direct manifestations, they are essentially slaves to the will of the entity. Partial avatars are one stepped removed, and are able to have more control of themselves and their actions.

As Purna avatars are huge, they can be cumbersome and difficult to move around in a smaller world. As such, a god in this form can divide its soul further into smaller bodies, each containing a piece of its soul. These bodies are still full avatars, as they contain pieces of the entity's soul rather than just an aspect of them. They operate as a hive mind, remaining in communication with each other and sharing experiences and knowledge. They transfer this information to the actual entity controlling all of them. The entity uses these bodies like a hub, allowing it to be in multiple places as once and rapidly increasing its processing power. However, there is a significant flaw in this. Even though the entity can rapidly process and access previously learned information, it is unable to take in new information. It cannot learn new skills or abilities, or gain any new knowledge of its surroundings. It can still observe and interact, but it is as if the brain of the entity is completely full and has run out of storage space. this is counter-intuitive, as more bodies should be able to increase its capacity for learning rather than speed up its thinking. How can this be the case?

Comment: This seems internally contradictory.  How can small avatars "share experiences and knowledge" if the entity "cannot gain any new knowledge"?

Comment: ". . . or gain any new knowledge of its surroundings. . . ." But this would make the avatars blind and deaf???

Comment: Or do you mean the avatars can see and learn but they cannot upload information to the god itself? The god can issue orders but not for example see through the avatars' senses. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Alright. So, we have these hive-mind creatures, these "Purna" avatars. And they share information. Sounds great! But in reality, there's a problem with these avatars: they're not a decentralized hive-mind. Their hive-mind has a clear hierarchy: one "nexus" avatar, and then everything else.

Whenever any lesser avatar learns anything, it sends that info straight to the nexus avatar. The nexus avatar then sends that info down to all of its subordinates. It's like your brain; when your eye sees a ball headed for your face, it sends the info to your brain, and your brain tells your body to dodge.

However, unlike your brain, the Nexus doesn't have 4 limbs to command: it has thousands. And all of them are constantly sending information to the nexus. Have you ever had a computer where one app is super laggy? That one app doesn't slow down: everything does.

It takes a small amount of time to transmit info from one avatar to the Nexus. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem — but their's a LOT of information to send around. The lines get clogged.

The nexus, then, is too busy shuffling around old information around to learn anything new. So it doesn't learn anything new.

Answer (score 0):

## It's impossible to communicate from the spiritual realm to the material realm

The two realms are divided and having a constant stream of information flowing from one to the other is a severe violation of the rules of physics. There are special times where communication is possible, but it's not a routine thing.

They managed anyway, breaking the universe to send a message but the bandwidth is extremely low. They can send a text message of one character a minute. This is enough to send simple messages and communicate back and forth, and coordinate on problem solving in both realms.

It's not enough for the Nexus to do any meaningful learning. They can send orders and receive basic information back, but they're fairly stubborn and have very little information on the ground. They have a lot of avatars, and a very limited communication channel, and so they mostly give orders and are hands off with their bodies.

## Their avatars often have problems with communication.

Suppose in the spiritual realms a rival deity steals one of their treasured possessions, and hops out during a planar alignment. They order their avatars over the course of 42 minutes "Burn every temple of that thieving god of desire". The avatars have an order. It doesn't matter if they find out the god stole the artifact from another who stole it before, and that it was meant to be returned. They have their orders.

They could try to tell the core entity, but their god might well be dealing with another crisis then, and have no free messages.

Answer (score 0):

### The higher level consciousness only commands the avatars, it is not the avatars themselves

The gods enter your reality in so much as the same way a human enters a videogame.  Inside a videogame, you may be a single character as you would be in a standard RPG, or you could be a group of characters as you would be in an RTS.  For a god to enter our world, he must choose how much of his avatar's existence here is automated to make sure that he is able to manage control just over the aspects of the avatar he cares about.  So when a god comes in as a Purna: he is one character, it is like playing Elder Scrolls: the avatar mostly just sits there awaiting instructions until the god interfaces with it.  Because the god is experiencing the game from a first person perspective, he is mostly learning what the character learns ... but what happens when the god is done playing Elder Scrolls, and instead decides to play Total War in our world?  Well the god can not directly puppet 1,000 avatars; so, what it does is it creates avatars with the knowledge that they need to perform their tasks.  Since you mentioned these avatars have more freewill, it can be assumed that any act of freewill is the behavior designed into the avatar as opposed to the direct behaviors of the god.

The god can still generally see what they are all doing, and co-ordinate them, but their activities are no longer a 1st-person experience.  They are just following pre-designed behaviors and taking orders just as needed.